# Retrieve interval value from an observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I've created an observable O,  with an interval of x. This is a silly question and it seem like it should be easy, but how do I find out O's interval. I can't just say something such as, O.getIntervalValue(), it seems like it is much more complicated than that?

```
combineLatest(Online, Mode, TestFrequency, watchRunTest()).pipe(
switchMap((_Properties): Observable<any> => {
        return _Properties[0] && _Properties[1] === "auto" ? interval( 
                      _Properties[2] * 60 * 1000) : never();
}))
.subscribe((_RunTest) => {
    this.setRunTest(new Date().getTime(), null)
});
```

Comment: I can't understand your question. The snippet doesn't seem to relate to the text (where is O?), and I can't figure out what you mean by "find out O's interval". Explain, with the simplest example you can imagine, what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: regardless the code, if O is an observable with an interval, I should be able to find out what it's interval is. The snipped show that the switchMap is returning an interval(i) or a never() to the watchRunTest(). I should be able to ask the observable for it's interval of its period such as O.interval.. I can't seem to do that. Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, no, it's not possible to do that. You'll find to find somewhere else to store that period.

Comment: You could emit the value as part of your result. If you could build a stackblitz with a demo of what you are trying to accomplish, I can show what I mean.

Comment: Here is a simple example, but I think you need it to do more that what I've shown here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l6go4k

Comment: @DeborahK Thanks Deborah! I'll post a stackblitz demo when I understand how to view the values of console.log when running stackblitz.. :-). I learned Angular from your vidoes! love them!

Comment: @DeborahK ok, I see how to view the console in stackblitz now.. lol